# How to revert to origin's master branch's version of file

Tags: git

I'm in my local computer's master branch of a cloned master-branch of a repo from a remote server.

I updated a file, and I want to revert back to the original version from the remote master branch.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1146, accepted):

Assuming you did not commit the file, or add it to the index, then:

```
git checkout -- filename
```

Assuming you added it to the index, but did not commit it, then:

```
git reset HEAD filename
git checkout -- filename
```

Assuming you did commit it, then:

```
git checkout origin/master filename
```

Assuming you want to blow away all commits from your branch (VERY DESTRUCTIVE):

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Your third option is very different from your first two options in that it touches all files and not just the one file. You may want to point this out more explicitly. Also why not recommend `git checkout HEAD filename` and `git checkout origin/master filename` for options one and two, it would be more consistent?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I added the `git checkout origin/master filename` option to gahooa's answer.

Comment: The last option doesn't specify the filename - how does that work?

Comment: @cilphex it blows away all of the commits in your current branch

Comment: I accidently rebased branchA off of branchB and needed to reset to master local branch. `git reset --hard master` alone was my solution since I didn't want to reach out to origin. Thanks.

Comment: @gahooa It should probably be git checkout -- filename, what if the file is called "master", then you would get a behaviour that was not intended.

Comment: I found I have to `rm filename` first. `git checkout filename` won't overwrite the changes in your current directory.

Comment: In "git checkout origin/master filename" what is syntax for multiple paths? Is it semicolon separated or blank space etc? In other words, I am looking for something like: "git checkout origin/master  path1;path2;path3"

Comment: What if that does not work because of unmerged files?

Comment: Interesting. I thought checkout was only for switching branches. What does the -- mean?

Comment: @MichaelL. - `git checkout` is used for switching branches when a branch is given, or for restoring content to the state of the index, when files are given.  The manual gives all the juicy details.

Comment: Very clear answer. To the point and precise. I wish my textbooks were like this.

Comment: Note that the "third option" mentioned by CBBailey is the `reset --hard` that has been edited to now be the fourth option.

Answer (score 71):

I've faced same problem and came across to this thread but my problem was with `upstream`. Below git command worked for me.

### Syntax

```
git checkout {remoteName}/{branch} -- {../path/file.js}
```

### Example

```
git checkout upstream/develop -- public/js/index.js
```

Comment: why do you need `--` ? for me works fine without it

Comment: @godblessstrawberry it helps command line arguments to always assume it's about a path / file

Answer (score 62):

Can also be done using [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

`git restore --source origin/master filename`

Comment: Finally, a simple git answer!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of adding an alternative (not necessarily a better one, of course), if you have already committed the file before, but now you need to undo the change, here's what you can do:

```
git diff HEAD..master -- path/to/file.ext | git apply -
```

This generates a diff to restore the file to the version in the `master` branch, and then applies it. The minus after `git apply` tells `git` to read the patch from standard input.

You can then commit the file as usual.

Here is the same command expressed as a shell function:

```
# Git Reset File
function grf() {
  git diff HEAD..master -- $1 | git apply -
}

# for example: grf ./someChangedFile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to find the latest commit id and the directory of the file you want to revert.

then using the following commands

```
git checkout [commit ID] -- path/to/file
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

will help you to revert the file you want to latest version of that file on remote computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't commit it to the master branch yet, its easy:

- get off the master branch (like `git checkout -b oops/fluke/dang`)
- commit your changes there (like `git add -u; git commit;`)
- go back the master branch (like `git checkout master`)

Your changes will be saved in branch oops/fluke/dang; master will be as it was.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore your files modified or deleted with:

`git restore yourFileName`

Or for every file:

`git restore .`